# Issues with guice

Tags: tomcat, guice

I am having issues with running a web app locally specifically when deploying it to tomcat.I know a lot of people posted information but sadly none of it helps me.Incidentally does the version of tomcat matter with guice issues?Because we use a different version of tomcat to deploy the web app remotely the one we use locally. Specifically I receive this error while trying to deploy locally:

Error in custom provider.

I can provide details if anyone is interested in helping me out.But for now I need to know whether the tomcat version is the culprit.

thanks,
Mukhtar Farid

Here's the stack trace:

```
108) Error in custom provider, java.lang.NullPointerException

  at org.eframeworks.layers.infrastructure.persistence.PersistenceModule.internalConfigure(PersistenceModule.java:357)
  while locating org.eframeworks.layers.infrastructure.factory.FactoryConfiguration
    for parameter 1 at org.eframeworks.layers.infrastructure.factory.GuicedObjectFactory.<init>(GuicedObjectFactory.java:49)
  at org.eframeworks.layers.infrastructure.factory.GuicedObjectFactory.class(GuicedObjectFactory.java:49)
  while locating org.eframeworks.layers.infrastructure.factory.GuicedObjectFactory
  at org.eframeworks.layers.infrastructure.persistence.PersistenceModule.internalConfigure(PersistenceModule.java:390)
  while locating org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.ObjectFactory
    for field at org.eframeworks.layers.infrastructure.persistence.ConfigurationProvider.objectFactory(ConfigurationProvider.java:236)
  at org.eframeworks.layers.infrastructure.persistence.ConfigurationProvider.class(ConfigurationProvider.java:43)
  while locating org.eframeworks.layers.infrastructure.persistence.ConfigurationProvider
  at org.eframeworks.layers.infrastructure.persistence.PersistenceModule.internalConfigure(PersistenceModule.java:382)
  while locating org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration
    for parameter 0 at org.mybatis.guice.session.SqlSessionFactoryProvider.createNewSqlSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactoryProvider.java:64)
  at org.mybatis.guice.session.SqlSessionFactoryProvider.class(SqlSessionFactoryProvider.java:31)
  while locating org.mybatis.guice.session.SqlSessionFactoryProvider
  at org.eframeworks.layers.infrastructure.persistence.PersistenceModule.internalConfigure(PersistenceModule.java:385)
  while locating org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory
    for parameter 0 at org.mybatis.guice.session.SqlSessionManagerProvider.createNewSqlSessionManager(SqlSessionManagerProvider.java:55)
  at org.mybatis.guice.session.SqlSessionManagerProvider.class(SqlSessionManagerProvider.java:31)
  while locating org.mybatis.guice.session.SqlSessionManagerProvider
  at org.eframeworks.layers.infrastructure.persistence.PersistenceModule.configure(PersistenceModule.java:187)
  while locating org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionManager
    for field at org.mybatis.guice.mappers.MapperProvider.sqlSessionManager(MapperProvider.java:40)
  while locating org.mybatis.guice.mappers.MapperProvider
  at com.google.inject.util.Providers$3.initialize(Providers.java:101)
  at org.eframeworks.layers.infrastructure.persistence.PersistenceModule.bindMapper(PersistenceModule.java:213)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.inject.internal.Initializer$InjectableReference.get(Initializer.java:147)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstantFactory.get(ConstantFactory.java:35)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.inject(SingleFieldInjector.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:94)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleMethodInjector.inject(SingleMethodInjector.java:83)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:94)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleMethodInjector.inject(SingleMethodInjector.java:83)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:94)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.inject(SingleFieldInjector.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:75)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectAndNotify(MembersInjectorImpl.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:60)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.injectMembers(InjectorImpl.java:944)
    at com.google.inject.util.Providers$3.initialize(Providers.java:101)
    at com.google.inject.util.Providers$3$$FastClassByGuice$$14d1a0ba.invoke(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastMethod.invoke(FastMethod.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleMethodInjector$1.invoke(SingleMethodInjector.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleMethodInjector.inject(SingleMethodInjector.java:90)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:75)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectAndNotify(MembersInjectorImpl.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Initializer$InjectableReference.get(Initializer.java:147)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Initializer.injectAll(Initializer.java:92)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:173)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
    at org.eframeworks.layers.controller.webapp.WebAppListener.getInjector(WebAppListener.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener.contextInitialized(GuiceServletContextListener.java:45)
    at org.eframeworks.layers.controller.webapp.WebAppListener.contextInitialized(WebAppListener.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5199)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Now I am not that familiar with Guice but I know some Java...and looking at this error this exception is obviously generated due to a null pointer as specified.But I want to know whether I am just using an older version of Guice...or is that an unrelated solution.Any help regarding this matter will be appreciated :)!
Cheers,
Mukhtar Farid

Comment: Tomcat version is not likely to be the culprit.  There should be more relevant text below the "error in custom provider", with backtraces and other helpful information.

Answer (score 1):

This stack trace looks like [this Guice bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=627), fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/google/guice/commit/6b7e7187bd074d3f2df9b04e17fa01e7592f295c).  Unfortunately there hasn't been a stable release of Guice since then, but if you can use the 4.0 betas then try that.  You can also comment on the bug [here](https://github.com/google/guice/issues/627) if you need help working around it; I don't quite understand the conditions that trigger it.